# Comparison between the original LibSVM and sklearn.svm.SVC

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

Is the scikit learn implementation version of LibSVM nearly as computationally efficient as the original LibSVM?

Does anyone have any stats on the comparison?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in comparison. Sklearn's SVC is just a **wrapper** around libsvm. So up to data manipulation "around" it (pre- and post processing), it is **exactly the same**.